# Tomcat treats my prometheus java agent jar as webapp deployment

Tags: tomcat

In my **~/.bash_profile**

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -javaagent:/home/server1/bin/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.13.0.jar=9107:/home/server1/bin/jmx_prometheus_config.yaml"
```

Error log:

```
2020-09-11 15:01:01,961 [prometheus-http-1-4] ERROR servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet  - Context initialization failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Grails requires a parent ApplicationContext, is the /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml file missing?
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getAttributes(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:709)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.getAttributes(JmxMBeanServer.java:705)
    at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.jmx.JmxScraper.scrapeBean(JmxScraper.java:151)
    at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.jmx.JmxScraper.doScrape(JmxScraper.java:117)
    at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.jmx.JmxCollector.collect(JmxCollector.java:473)
    at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.client.CollectorRegistry$MetricFamilySamplesEnumeration.findNextElement(CollectorRegistry.java:190)
    at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.client.CollectorRegistry$MetricFamilySamplesEnumeration.nextElement(CollectorRegistry.java:223)
    at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.client.CollectorRegistry$MetricFamilySamplesEnumeration.nextElement(CollectorRegistry.java:144)
    at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.client.exporter.common.TextFormat.write004(TextFormat.java:22)
    at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.client.exporter.HTTPServer$HTTPMetricHandler.handle(HTTPServer.java:68)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:82)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

If I understand this right, tomcat is treating the javaagent jar as a webapp to deploy.. What configuration should I check to make sure that tomcat should just treat this jar as an agent and not as a webapp?

```
Server version: Apache Tomcat/8.0.12
Server built:   Aug 29 2014 03:46:23
Server number:  8.0.12.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     2.6.32-754.33.1.el6.x86_64
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.8.0_144-b01
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was gone when we use tomcat version 8.5.X